# Maxdop setting in SQL Server 2014 during index rebuild offline and online

Tags: sql-server, index, sql-server-2014

We are having issues performing index, table and stats maintenance in one of our databases.
There are over 200 indexes, some of them on tables having more than 1b rows.

We can't bring application down(it is required 24/7) to perform offline rebuild for certain tables, so we keep them with online option

However, to speed things up (as maintenance takes over 24hrs), our DBAs came up with the idea to split the scopes and run 2 streams of maintenance: offline and online at the same time.

Moreover, they advised to set maxdop to 16 for offline and 24 for online rebuild having SQL server 32vCPUs in total.

My concerns are:

1. Does having two very resource intensive tasks at the same time or
   simultaneously will be too much for server having 32vCPUs, 120GB
   RAM, DB size of 1,5TB in total?
2. Does MAXDOP 16 and 24 running at the same time cause "overprovisioning" and queueing like in ESXi/VMware for example?

Comment: Do you have evidence that defrag actually buy you anything? Perhaps you see better performance, but that is because a rebuild also produced new statistics? I.e., a stats update would be sufficient...

Comment: The index rebuilds are most likely going to be IO constrained, not CPU constrained, so your main issue is going to be what IO you have

Comment: I know you question is not about that, but have you verified if you really need over 200 indexes in some tables? I'm not saying it is wrong, because it depend of you needs. But if you have so large number of the indexes I would verified if all of them are needed and used. If database is only used to read data then maybe fragmentation is not a big issue and only update statistics should be done more often.

Comment: @Marcin I took it to mean he has over 200 indexes to perform maintenance on in total (spread across multiple tables). Hopefully that's so, otherwise there's probably other design issues going on. Milosz, as other's suggested, index rebuilds are generally not necessary or at least should not needed to be done often. See this [Tara Kizer article](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/12/index-maintenance-madness/) which loosely talks about the lack of necessity and recommends not rebuilding when under 80% or even 90% fragmented. I've personally found almost no use for rebuilding them myself.

Comment: [Should I Rebuild Indexes?](https://am2.co/should-i-rebuild-indexes/)